# Bash scripting on debian installer not accepting user input on preseeding

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh

I have a very small script **that needs to be run on debian installer:** *(via preseeding, pre installation script)*

```
echo -n -e " # Your option [1] [2] [3]: "
    read REPLY
    if [ "$REPLY" == "1" ]
```

The script stops here and whatever I press is just displayed onto screen however it is not accepting the enter key. Normally, when you press 1 and press enter, the read should return 1 to $REPLY. But nothing happens. It keeps accepting user input but no further action happens.

Then, I switched to tty2 with ALT+F2 and run the script there, it was fine, it works as expected, when I press; it takes the input. Why tty1 is not accepting enter as usual?

Comment: Can you post the full script, or at least more of it?

Comment: Please do change your no-argument `read` to `read REPLY`. There's no sense in using that bashism. If there's still trouble, switch to tty2 and run `ps t1` there to find out what processes are active on tty1 and whether they're running (`R` state) or sleeping (`S` state)

Comment: it normally works, it does not work on debian-installer& busybox environment on tty1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [debconf](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html) for that kind of configuration, it tackles exactly needs like yours.

#### Adapted example from the manual

Template file (`debian/templates`):

```
Template: your_package/select_option
Type: select
Choices: 1, 2, 3
Description: Which option?
 Choose one of the options
```

Script (`debian/config`):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

db_input medium your_package/select_option || true
db_go

# Check their answer.
db_get your_package/select_option
if [ "$RET" = "1" ]; then
   # Do stuff
fi
```

Comment: Any thoughts how can I embed it into installer, in the beginning of the installation? I want it to be first question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem (read not processing my input) with busybox on an embedded Linux.
Took me some time to realize that busybox's read is not CR-tolerant — my terminal program (used miniterm.py) sent CR/LF line ends by default;  switching it to LF only solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

with bash interpreter, try replace read by :

builtin read

with other sh interpreter, specify the variable name :

read REPLY

Comment: can you add `ps -p $$` before read, to verify the script is interprted by bash

Comment: it's in busybox so it should be just sh

Answer (score 0):

The following script works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n -e " # Your option [1] [2] [3]: "
read

case $REPLY in
    1 ) 
      echo "one" ;;
    2 ) 
      echo "two" ;;
    3 ) 
        echo "three" ;;
    *)
        echo "invalid" ;;
esac
```

It prints out `one` nicely if I choose <kbd>1</kbd>. Any reason why you'd like to stick to `if`...`fi`?